# Why does flipping my sprites cause it to move weird

Tags: python, object, pygame, sprite, flip

I'm making a pyGame game and instead of getting sprites to both sides I decided to just flip it horizontally, the thing is it move perfect on the right side but on the left side it moves wrong like the center of the image changes every frame, is there anyway I can controll the images center.
for the record the function draw is being called from Main.py

This is my Player Class:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, char_type, x, y, scale, speed):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.alive = True
        self.char_type = char_type
        self.speed = speed
        self.direction = 1
        self.vel_y = 0
        self.jump = False
        self.in_air = True
        self.flip = False
        self.attack = False
        self.moving_left = False
        self.moving_right = False
        self.animation_list = []
        self.frame_index = 0
        self.action = 0
        self.update_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        
        #load all images for the players
        animation_types = ['stand', 'walk', 'jump', 'attack1', 'attack2', 'attack3']
        for animation in animation_types:
            #reset temporary list of images
            temp_list = []
            #count number of files in the folder
            num_of_frames = len(os.listdir(f'sprites/{self.char_type}/{animation}'))
            for i in range(num_of_frames):
                img = pygame.image.load(f'sprites/{self.char_type}/{animation}/{i}.png')
                img = pygame.transform.scale(img, (int(img.get_width() * scale), int(img.get_height() * scale)))
                temp_list.append(img)
            self.animation_list.append(temp_list)

        self.image = self.animation_list[self.action][self.frame_index]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (x, y)


    def move(self, GRAVITY):
        #reset movement variables
        dx = 0
        dy = 0

        #assign movement variables if moving left or right
        if self.moving_left:
            dx = -self.speed
            self.flip = True
            self.direction = -1
        if self.moving_right:
            dx = self.speed
            self.flip = False
            self.direction = 1

        # if self.attack:
            # self.play_sound("attack")

        #jump
        if self.jump == True and self.in_air == False:
            self.vel_y = -11
            self.jump = False
            self.in_air = True

        # if self.attack == True:
        #     self.attack = False

        #apply gravity
        self.vel_y += GRAVITY
        if self.vel_y > 10:
            self.vel_y
        dy += self.vel_y

        #check collision with floor
        if self.rect.bottom + dy > 450:
            dy = 450 - self.rect.bottom
            self.in_air = False

        #update rectangle position
        self.rect.x += dx
        self.rect.y += dy


    def update_animation(self):
        #update animation
        if self.action == 0:
            animation_cooldown = 800
        elif self.action == 1:
            animation_cooldown = 170
        elif self.action == 2:
            animation_cooldown = 50
        elif self.action == 3:
            self.moving_left = False
            self.moving_right = False
            animation_cooldown = 250
            # self.action = random.randint(3, 5)
        #update image depending on current frame
        self.image = self.animation_list[self.action][self.frame_index]
        #check if enough time has passed since the last update
        if pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.update_time > animation_cooldown:
            self.update_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
            self.frame_index += 1
        #if the animation has run out the reset back to the start
        if self.frame_index >= len(self.animation_list[self.action]):
            if self.action == 3:
                self.attack = False
            self.frame_index = 0



    def update_action(self, new_action):
        #check if the new action is different to the previous one
        if new_action != self.action:
            self.action = new_action
            #update the animation settings
            self.frame_index = 0
            self.update_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    
    def play_sound(self, sound):
        soundObj = pygame.mixer.Sound('sprites/sounds/player/' + sound + '.mp3')
        soundObj.play()
        




    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(pygame.transform.flip(self.image, self.flip, False), self.rect)
```

Comment: Where is this draw function called from? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: I Updated it, the function draw is being called from the main, also now I posted the full code of the player class

Answer (score 0):

You need to reverse the list for the flipped side. [`reverse`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) the list in place:

```py
temp_list.reverse()            
self.animation_list.append(temp_list)
```

or append a [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) list:

```py
self.animation_list.append(reversed(temp_list))
```

---

If your images are different sizes, you need to create images of the same size. Find the size of the largest image. Create a `pygame.Surface` for each image and `blit` the image onto the *Surface*:

```py
for animation in animation_types:

    max_image_size = [0, 0]       
    temp_list = []
    num_of_frames = len(os.listdir(f'sprites/{self.char_type}/{animation}'))
    for i in range(num_of_frames):
        img = pygame.image.load(f'sprites/{self.char_type}/{animation}/{i}.png')
        temp_list.append(img)
        max_image_size[0] = max(max_image_size[0], img.get_width())
        max_image_size[0] = max(max_image_size[1], img.get_height())
        
    for i in range(num_of_frames):
        img = pygame.Surface(max_image_size, pygame.SRCALPHA)        
        img.blit(temp_list[i], (0, 0))
        temp_list[i] = pygame.transform.scale(img, (int(img.get_width() * scale), int(img.get_height() * scale)))
        
    self.animation_list.append(temp_list)
```

Comment: Sorry, for the misunderstanding but my frames orders is fine, the thing is the center of the img changes every frame so it looks like it pushes the player backwards.

Comment: @Hawanity So your approach only works for images of the same size. Sorry, but there is good and clean way to solve this for images with different size. You must ensure that the images are all the same size. However, the problem depends on the content of the image, no one can answer this question without seeing the images.

Comment: @Hawanity If your images are the same size, there is no mathematical reason for the problem. Either it works for the left and right side or it doesn't work at all.